# LiveData multiple queries to DB

Tags: android, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

In my app i have got Pojo object which retrieve data from Firestore, but this Pojo object needs also data from other locations in Firestore thus i have to perform more than one query to database. I don't know how to notify my UI only when all queries are done. Could you please help me how to achieve that with LiveData?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I read about MediatorLiveData, but if I add two sources to it I dont know if first or second request is completed. Should I use statement "if" in onChaned functions to check if first or second livedata has value and only then I use setValue on MediatorLiveData?